# SQL JOB with html report

Tags: html, sql, t-sql, ssms

This is the code that is supposed to return an html report by and ssms job.

```
DECLARE @DataInicialMesAnterior DATE, @DataFinalMesAnterior DATE;
SET @DataInicialMesAnterior = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0);
SET @DataFinalMesAnterior = DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0));

DECLARE @tableHTML2 NVARCHAR(MAX), @corpo2 AS NVARCHAR(50);
SET @tableHTML2 =
    N'<font size="1"><H1>Produção Mensal Tecelagem Entre ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @DataInicialMesAnterior, 104) + ' - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @DataFinalMesAnterior, 104) + '  </H1> ' +
    N'<style> th {color:#FFFFFF; background-color: #6193AC } </style>' +
    N'<table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">' +
    N'<tr><th rowspan="3">Maquina</th><th rowspan="3">Artigo</th><th rowspan="3">Descrição</th><th rowspan="3">Total Metros</th><th rowspan="3">Total Kgs</th></tr>' +
    N'<tr></tr><tr><th></th></tr>' +
    CAST((
        WITH ProductionData AS (
            SELECT 
                'Tear - ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(cast(substring(BI.U_MED1, 2, 2) as int)))) as td, 
                BI.REF as td1, 
                ISNULL(ST.design, '') as td2, --design
                SUM(CASE WHEN stobs.u_dobramal=1 THEN BI.QTT*2 ELSE bi.qtt END) as 'Metros Produzidos', -- Soma de metros por tear e ref
                SUM(CAST(BI.U_MED3 as float)) as 'Kgs Produzidos' -- Soma de kgs por tear e ref
            FROM carlom.dbo.BI bi (nolock)
            LEFT JOIN carlom.dbo.st ST (nolock) ON ST.ref = BI.REF
            INNER JOIN carlom.dbo.stobs stobs (nolock) ON st.ref = stobs.ref 
            WHERE BI.NDOS = 20 
                AND BI.u_data2 BETWEEN @DataInicialMesAnterior AND @DataFinalMesAnterior
            GROUP BY 'Tear - ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(cast(substring(BI.U_MED1, 2, 2) as int)))), BI.REF, ST.design
        ), Totals AS (
            SELECT 
                td, 
                td1, 
                MAX(td2) as td2, 
                SUM([Metros Produzidos]) as 'Metros Produzidos', 
                SUM([Kgs Produzidos]) as 'Kgs Produzidos'
            FROM ProductionData
            GROUP BY td, td1
            HAVING SUM([Metros Produzidos]) > 0 OR SUM([Kgs Produzidos]) > 0
        ), AllData AS (
            SELECT 
                td, 
                td1, 
                MAX(td2) as td2, 
                SUM([Metros Produzidos]) as 'Metros Produzidos', 
                SUM([Kgs Produzidos]) as 'Kgs Produzidos'
            FROM Totals
            GROUP BY td, td1
            HAVING SUM([Metros Produzidos]) > 0 OR SUM([Kgs Produzidos]) > 0
        ), OrderedData AS (
            SELECT 
                td, 
                td1, 
                MAX(td2) as td2, 
                SUM([Metros Produzidos]) as 'Metros Produzidos', 
                SUM([Kgs Produzidos]) as 'Kgs Produzidos',
                0 as TotalOrder
            FROM AllData
            GROUP BY td, td1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 
                'Total' as td, 
                '' as td1, 
                '' as td2, 
                SUM([Metros Produzidos]) as 'Metros Produzidos', 
                SUM([Kgs Produzidos]) as 'Kgs Produzidos',
                1 as TotalOrder
            FROM AllData
        )
        SELECT 
            td, 
            td1, 
            MAX(td2) as td2, 
            MAX([Metros Produzidos]) as 'Metros Produzidos', 
            MAX([Kgs Produzidos]) as 'Kgs Produzidos'
        FROM OrderedData
        GROUP BY td, td1, TotalOrder
        ORDER BY 
            CASE WHEN TotalOrder = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
            CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(td, LEN('Tear - ') + 1, LEN(td))) = 1 THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(td, LEN('Tear - ') + 1, LEN(td)) AS INT) ELSE 99999 END, 
            td
        FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')) + N'</font></table>';

SET @corpo2 = 'Produção do Mês';

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'PHC',
    @recipients = 'david.sousa@bnextconsulting.com',
    @subject = @corpo2,
    @body = @tableHTML2,
    @body_format = 'HTML';
```

the code retrieves the following errors

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.
> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 26
> Incorrect syntax near ','.
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 36
> Incorrect syntax near ','.
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 46
> Incorrect syntax near ','.
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 79
> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: The errors are telling you the problem. You clearly, for example, have a `WITH` clause inside a `CAST` function.

Comment: i understand that, i'm new to this. so can you help solving the code.

Comment: The `WITH` needs to go *before* your `SELECT` (you're currently using a `SET`). Also you have a `CAST` with no datatype. It's `CAST(<Expression> AS <Data Type>)`.

Answer (score 0):

You've dumped a bunch of CTE declarations inside a `CAST` function; that isn't allow. CTEs must be defined at the *start* of the statement not half way through. YOu also have a `CAST` but no `AS <Data Type>` clause. I half address that, but you'll need to add the data type.

```sql
DECLARE @DataInicialMesAnterior DATE, @DataFinalMesAnterior DATE;
SET @DataInicialMesAnterior = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0);
SET @DataFinalMesAnterior = DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0));

DECLARE @tableHTML2 NVARCHAR(MAX), @corpo2 AS NVARCHAR(50);
WITH ProductionData AS (
            SELECT 
                'Tear - ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(cast(substring(BI.U_MED1, 2, 2) as int)))) as td, 
                BI.REF as td1, 
                ISNULL(ST.design, '') as td2, --design
                SUM(CASE WHEN stobs.u_dobramal=1 THEN BI.QTT*2 ELSE bi.qtt END) as 'Metros Produzidos', -- Soma de metros por tear e ref
                SUM(CAST(BI.U_MED3 as float)) as 'Kgs Produzidos' -- Soma de kgs por tear e ref
            FROM carlom.dbo.BI bi (nolock)
            LEFT JOIN carlom.dbo.st ST (nolock) ON ST.ref = BI.REF
            INNER JOIN carlom.dbo.stobs stobs (nolock) ON st.ref = stobs.ref 
            WHERE BI.NDOS = 20 
                AND BI.u_data2 BETWEEN @DataInicialMesAnterior AND @DataFinalMesAnterior
            GROUP BY 'Tear - ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(cast(substring(BI.U_MED1, 2, 2) as int)))), BI.REF, ST.design
        ), Totals AS (
            SELECT 
                td, 
                td1, 
                MAX(td2) as td2, 
                SUM([Metros Produzidos]) as 'Metros Produzidos', 
                SUM([Kgs Produzidos]) as 'Kgs Produzidos'
            FROM ProductionData
            GROUP BY td, td1
            HAVING SUM([Metros Produzidos]) > 0 OR SUM([Kgs Produzidos]) > 0
        ), AllData AS (
            SELECT 
                td, 
                td1, 
                MAX(td2) as td2, 
                SUM([Metros Produzidos]) as 'Metros Produzidos', 
                SUM([Kgs Produzidos]) as 'Kgs Produzidos'
            FROM Totals
            GROUP BY td, td1
            HAVING SUM([Metros Produzidos]) > 0 OR SUM([Kgs Produzidos]) > 0
        ), OrderedData AS (
            SELECT 
                td, 
                td1, 
                MAX(td2) as td2, 
                SUM([Metros Produzidos]) as 'Metros Produzidos', 
                SUM([Kgs Produzidos]) as 'Kgs Produzidos',
                0 as TotalOrder
            FROM AllData
            GROUP BY td, td1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 
                'Total' as td, 
                '' as td1, 
                '' as td2, 
                SUM([Metros Produzidos]) as 'Metros Produzidos', 
                SUM([Kgs Produzidos]) as 'Kgs Produzidos',
                1 as TotalOrder
            FROM AllData
        )
SELECT @tableHTML2 =
    N'<font size="1"><H1>Produção Mensal Tecelagem Entre ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @DataInicialMesAnterior, 104) + N' - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @DataFinalMesAnterior, 104) + N'  </H1> ' +
    N'<style> th {color:#FFFFFF; background-color: #6193AC } </style>' +
    N'<table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">' +
    N'<tr><th rowspan="3">Maquina</th><th rowspan="3">Artigo</th><th rowspan="3">Descrição</th><th rowspan="3">Total Metros</th><th rowspan="3">Total Kgs</th></tr>' +
    N'<tr></tr><tr><th></th></tr>' +
    CAST((
        SELECT 
            td, 
            td1, 
            MAX(td2) as td2, 
            MAX([Metros Produzidos]) as 'Metros Produzidos', 
            MAX([Kgs Produzidos]) as 'Kgs Produzidos'
        FROM OrderedData
        GROUP BY td, td1, TotalOrder
        ORDER BY 
            CASE WHEN TotalOrder = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
            CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(td, LEN('Tear - ') + 1, LEN(td))) = 1 THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(td, LEN('Tear - ') + 1, LEN(td)) AS INT) ELSE 99999 END, 
            td
        FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS <DATA TYPE>) + N'</font></table>';

SET @corpo2 = N'Produção do Mês';

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'PHC',
    @recipients = 'david.sousa@bnextconsulting.com',
    @subject = @corpo2,
    @body = @tableHTML2,
    @body_format = 'HTML';
```

Comment: I know you just copied from OP but `LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(cast(... as int))))` just hilarious, along with all the `nolock` and various other badness.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just wanted to make sure you get `nvarchar(max)`, but `FOR XML` anyway does that if you don't specify `,TYPE`.

There are various other issues with the code also:

- `LEFT JOIN` followed by an `INNER JOIN` which is dependent on the former makes no sense: either both should be `INNER` or both `LEFT` (or you can nest the join conditions).
- Do not use `nolock`, it has serious data integrity implications.
- `Totals` and `AllData` are eaxctly the same. There is no further aggregation being done, because they are grouping by the same columns.
- `OrderedData` and the `UNION ALL` can also be elided by using `GROUPING SETS`. The `GROUPING()` function will tell you whether the row has been grouped for a column.
- `LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(cast(substring(...) as int))))` is nonsense: integers casted to string don't need trimming. Futhermore why cast to `int` only to cast it back? If you want to make sure it's an `int` without throwing an error, just use `TRY_CAST`.
- Don't add `TEAR -`  onto the value at the beginning, as it's less efficient for grouping, and you have to query it back out afterwards. Instead tack it on in the final stage.
- Always specify `VARCHAR` and `NVARCHAR` with a length.
- Do not use `''` to quote column names, only `[]`.
- Instead of `ORDER BY CASE WHEN TotalOrder = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` just do `ODRER BY TotalOrder`.
- Use `EOMONTH` to get the end of a month, and use `DATEFROMPARTS` to construct dates. In newer versions you can also use `DATETRUNC(month`.

```sql
DECLARE @DataFinalMesAnterior DATE = EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1);
DECLARE @DataInicialMesAnterior DATE = DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(year, @DataFinalMesAnterior), DATEPART(month, @DataFinalMesAnterior), 1);

DECLARE @tableHTML2 NVARCHAR(MAX), @corpo2 AS NVARCHAR(50);

WITH ProductionData AS (
    SELECT 
      ISNULL(TRY_CAST(SUBSTRING(BI.U_MED1, 2, 2) as int), 99999) as td, 
      BI.REF as td1, 
      ISNULL(ST.design, '') as td2, --design
      SUM(BI.QTT * IIF(stobs.u_dobramal = 1, 2, 1)) as [Metros Produzidos], -- Soma de metros por tear e ref
      SUM(CAST(BI.U_MED3 as float)) as [Kgs Produzidos] -- Soma de kgs por tear e ref
    FROM carlom.dbo.BI bi
    INNER JOIN carlom.dbo.st ST ON ST.ref = BI.REF
    INNER JOIN carlom.dbo.stobs stobs ON st.ref = stobs.ref 
    WHERE BI.NDOS = 20 
      AND BI.u_data2 BETWEEN @DataInicialMesAnterior AND @DataFinalMesAnterior
    GROUP BY
      ISNULL(TRY_CAST(SUBSTRING(BI.U_MED1, 2, 2) as int), 99999),
      BI.REF,
      ST.design
),

Totals AS (
    SELECT
      td AS tdOrdering,
      IIF(GROUPING(td) = 0, CONCAT('Tear - ', IIF(td = 99999, NULL, td)), 'Total') AS td, 
      IIF(GROUPING(td) = 0, td1, '') AS td1, 
      IIF(GROUPING(td) = 0, MAX(td2), '') as td2, 
      SUM([Metros Produzidos]) as [Metros Produzidos],
      SUM([Kgs Produzidos]) as [Kgs Produzidos],
      GROUPING(td) as TotalOrder
    FROM ProductionData
    GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
        (td, td1),
        ()
    )
    HAVING SUM([Metros Produzidos]) > 0
        OR SUM([Kgs Produzidos]) > 0
)

SELECT @tableHTML2 =
    N'<font size="1"><H1>Produção Mensal Tecelagem Entre ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), @DataInicialMesAnterior, 104) + N' - ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), @DataFinalMesAnterior, 104) + N'  </H1> ' +
    N'<style> th {color:#FFFFFF; background-color: #6193AC } </style>' +
    N'<table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">' +
    N'<tr><th rowspan="3">Maquina</th><th rowspan="3">Artigo</th><th rowspan="3">Descrição</th><th rowspan="3">Total Metros</th><th rowspan="3">Total Kgs</th></tr>' +
    N'<tr></tr><tr><th></th></tr>' +
    (
        SELECT 
          td,
          td1,
          td2,
          [Metros Produzidos],
          [Kgs Produzidos]
        FROM OrderedData
        ORDER BY 
            TotalOrder,
            tdOrdering
        FOR XML PATH('tr')
    ) + N'</font></table>';
```